# Pass which member of a class to access in another class's method

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

I understand that the title can be confusing so let me describe the problem. I am currently refactoring a section of our codebase.

We have a bunch of classes: say `A`, `B`, `C`. These classes are mostly similar and are an easy refactoring target except for this one line that I am struggling with:

```
// In Class A
SomeType x = r?.abc?.FirstOrDefault();

// In Class B
SomeType x = r?.def?.FirstOrDefault();

// In Class C
SomeType x = r?.ghi?.FirstOrDefault();
```

`r` is an object that gets populated before this particular statement. That class has a bunch of members: `abc`, `def`, `ghi`, etc. Each of these classes `a`, `b`, `c` accesses only one of them. How to refactor these statements in the new base class that I am writing?

```
public class BaseClass {
    public T SomeMethod<T>(var param1, var param2, var member) {
        // Some processing. `r` gets populated
        SomeType x = r?.member?.FirstOrDefault(); // I want to do something like this but obviously this won't work. How to solve this?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract SomeType GetX(OtherType r);

    … SomeType x = GetX(r);
}

public class A
{
    protected override SomeType GetX(OtherType r) => r?.abc?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Which member of r each class accesses is class-specific behavior, and should go in each class.

Comment: This looks more elegant too. Will try this out as well. Thanks.

Comment: This does force me to make `BaseClass` as `abstract` though.

Comment: Sure it does. I was under the impression that the three classes are *mostly* similar, and not exactly the same. Which means they get to share an abstract base class.

Comment: Yeah that's not an issue. `abstract` makes sense tbh

Comment: Plus 1 for the design.